# How do I set a bot's avatar?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am using the Discord.JS library, with version 12 at the time that I am writing this. I would like for my bot's avatar to automatically change every april fools day, because I think it would be interesting. Is this possible? I could not find the solution for this anywhere online, so I had figured that asking here would be a way to obtain the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ClientUser.setAvatar()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setAvatar) to change the bot's avatar, and [`cron`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) to schedule the change every april.

```js
// <client> is a placeholder for your Discord.Client()
client.user.setAvatar('./image.png');
```